# Bootstrap Panel Close Button

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to create a button to dismiss a panel in it's heading. It is doing what it is supposed to, but I'm getting double symbols. The `&times;` symbol is being doubled.

My HTML code is:

```html
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="panel panel-primary fade in collapse" id="test"><div class="container"></div>
    <div class="panel-heading"><a data-toggle="collapse" href="#test" class="close">&times;</a>
        <h3 class="panel-title">Detalhes do Planeamento</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">
    </div>
</div>
```

It is being displayed like this:

[image]

Why is that? Can I also make the cross red? Or any kind of red background so it pops out?

Comment: it is working fine.

Comment: Is it ok for you? @AjaySinghDeopa with only one symbol?

Comment: yes. See in the snippet

Comment: Yes, I see it is working on the snippet. Although I cannot use it because my website gets all buggy... It's being developed in an older version :(

Comment: Which bootstrap version are you using?

Comment: @AjaySinghDeopa I'm using version 2.3.2